# scala - custom (complex?) distinct function on a list of sets of a case class

Tags: list, scala, set, case-class

I have a simple case class:

```
case class OneTwo (one: String, two: String)
```

I have a simple list of sets of this case class:

```
val list = List(Set(OneTwo("a", "b")), Set(OneTwo("a", "b"), OneTwo("c", "d")), Set(OneTwo("e", "f")))
```

Now I have an unusual "distinct" requirement on this list: if one set is contained in another, they are equal, and the survivor should be the smaller set. E.g. in the above `list` the "ditsinct" procedure should return `List(Set(OneTwo("a", "b")), Set(OneTwo("e", "f")))`, because `Set(OneTwo("a", "b"))` is contained within `Set(OneTwo("a", "b"), OneTwo("c", "f"))` and `Set(OneTwo("a", "b"))` is smaller in size.

Now, the following works in the REPL and compiles, (see the "but" later):

```
def ord: Ordering[Set[OneTwo]] = new Ordering[Set[OneTwo]]() {
  def compare(set1: Set[OneTwo], set2: Set[OneTwo]): Int = {
    if (set1.equals(set2) || set1.subsetOf(set2) || set2.subsetOf(set1)) 0 else if (set1.size != set2.size) set1.size compare set2.size else
      set1.hashCode compare set2.hashCode
  }
}

val listSorted = list.sorted(ord).reverse

val listDistinct =  collection.immutable.SortedSet(listSorted: _*)(ord).toList

listDistinct
```

Gives:

```
List[scala.collection.immutable.Set[OneTwo]] = List(Set(OneTwo(e,f)), Set(OneTwo(a,b)))
```

BUT:
This ordering violates the Transitivity requiremnt of an ordering, therefore at run time this would throw a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` Exception.

Very simple to see why:

```
scala> ord.compare(Set(OneTwo("a","b")), Set(OneTwo("e", "f")))
res56: Int = -1

scala> ord.compare(Set(OneTwo("e","f")), Set(OneTwo("a", "b"), OneTwo("c", "d")))
res57: Int = -1

scala> ord.compare(Set(OneTwo("a","b")), Set(OneTwo("a", "b"), OneTwo("c", "d")))
res58: Int = 0
```

Which means A < B, B < C yet A = C. A problem.

Bottom-line: is there any way I could do what I want to do to my list of sets of OneTwo case class? (I don't care by the way about the final order of this list, it could also result in a Set, and it doesn't have to be similar to my strategy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a straightforward solution, I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it:

```
list.sortBy(_.size).foldLeft(Set.empty[Set[OneTwo]])((res, set) => {
  if (res.exists(_.subsetOf(set))) res else res + set 
}).toList
```

Sorting by size is important because your smaller sets will appear in the front in this way. After that, simply fold the list only adding an element if it satisfies your constraint. Note that we accumulate results in `Set`, not in `List`, because it makes constraint checking simpler and more efficient.

Comment: `...foldLeft(Set.empty[Set[OneTwo]])...` in my case. Thanks! Testing it now.

Comment: Oh, right. I was testing it in REPL on a simpler data structure. Fixed.